# Does the term 'noon' have exact meaning?

Tags: meaning, differences, time

Say I have a meeting at 10:00 and want to postpone it to around 13:00, can I ask the other to "postpone it to noon, around 13:00"? Or the term 'noon' means exactly 12:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noon means exactly mid-day, 12:00.

This is the definition you get if you google "define noon", and in usage it is not taken to mean a wider period of the day.

In your example, I would say "let's postpone till after noon - around 13:00?"

Comment: Or I might say "let's postpone till the afternoon - around 13:00". which means the same thing, but uses the noun "afternoon" instead of the noun "noon"!   In one case, you need the article "the", in the other you don't.   It's my impression, though I don't have anything to back it up, that if I said "postpone till after noon", I'm meaning soon after noon, early in the afternoon, whearas if I said "let's postpone till the afternoon", then I'd be talking about some time  later in the afternoon.

Comment: I don't think I would call 13.00 'afternoon' (though technically it is). I would probably say 'Let's postpone it till the middle of the day, say about 1.oo o'clock', or 'till around lunchtime'.

Comment: Yes - I agree, that's why I put "after noon" rather than "the afternoon" in my answer, but I thought it interesting to elaborate on the subtle difference in a comment :)   If asked "Is 13:00 in the afternoon?" you would have to say "yes".    But the sentence in the answer is better than the alternative in the comment.

Comment: As I have mentioned before on the site I am inclined to get annoyed by people (mostly telephonists) who, at one minute after 12.00 start saying 'good afternoon'. For me the afternoon starts after I have had lunch, usually about 13.00. In speech it would be impossible to distinguish between 'after noon' and 'afternoon'.

Comment: They are clearly distinguished in speech - one requires the use of the word "the", and is talking about postponing to the period defined by the noun "afternoon".  The other uses the adjective "after" to apply to the noun "noon" (which is why it sounds to me closer to noon than "the afternoon").